Using core data in a swiftUI view presented from a primarily swift project
Is it possible to use Core Data in a SwiftUI view that's largely a Swift project? I ask because when I try to get the managed object context from my Swift project into my SwiftUI view all examples are saying it needs to be set first on the top level SwiftUI view like this:
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataController.shared.container.viewContext)
        .environmentObject(coreDataViewModel)
}

Unfortunately, I don't have a top-level SwiftUI view so this is causing problems. Is there another way to set the MOC on the SwiftUI view or am I going to have to nest my initial Swift view inside a SwiftUI view in order to use Core Data?

You can set it for each window where you need it.

@JoakimDanielson Thanks- do you have any examples? I've tried putting the above in various places in my SwiftUI view and it just says Cannot find 'ContentView' in scope

See the answer below, just add the .environment(...) on your view

@JoakimDanielson No joy I'm afraid. I now have...
List(items) { item in
Text(item.value ?? "Unknown")
}.environment(.managedObjectContext, DataController.shared.container.viewContext)
... and it's reporting Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator. Yet that same context is reading data just fine in the UIKit parts of the app :(

Finally got it working by applying environment in UIKit before presenting the SwiftUI view, i.e.
      let swiftUIView = MySwiftUIViewController().environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataController.shared.container.viewContext)
      present(UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView), animated: true, completion: nil)

      This all seems a little fragile and I couldn't get it to work any other way. I even found environment needs to be set inline with the result of initialising MySwiftUIViewController- setting it on swiftUIView on a separate line will not work :/


Yes you can mix UIKit and SwiftUI or any other interface.
Swift is the language they share.
“Top level” can be the first SwiftUI view
AnySwiftUIView()
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataController.shared.container.viewContext)

Note that you can also use @ObservedObject To monitor any CoreData object that is passed in as an argument.
You only have to put it in an environment if the views need to access it.
Use SwiftUI with UIKit

Ah I see. Also complicating things, I'm using the body variable to build the page so I needed to set the environment inside that it seems, rather than apply the above to the body variable. Now I've added this inside body the app completely seizes up but I guess that's another issue entirely :/ Thanks anyway!

@bcl the body variable shouldn't be accessed from the parent, SwiftUI is not like UIKit, it is value based and your views will never be in sync. Watch the video I attached.

Yep, I'll definitely have a watch. I've clearly got the wrong idea how this works :)
